# Regex returns groups when testing but not in code?

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

I have the following code that I am using to extract three groups from a piece of text:

```
#sample test string: 'Photo Badge <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/surveyplanet/image/upload/v1384554966/gdm1z8joraciwjszpygg.png">'
pattern = ///
    (.*)                #Match all text before the image tag
    <img\ssrc="(.*)">   #Match the image tag and extract the image URL
    (.*)                #Match all text after the image tag
///g
_.map question.choices, (choice) ->
    [pre, url, post] = choice.choice_text.match(pattern)[1..3]
    console.log 'pre', pre
    console.log 'post', post
    console.log 'url', url
```

For some reason, no matter what I pass in the only group being populated is `pre`.  I have tested the same regex [here](http://regexr.com/39cee) and it groups as expected.  Can anyone see why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `g`  flag in your RegExp. According to MDN JS docs, [String::match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [RegExp::exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) have a different behavior when `g` flag is present.

So, instead of returning all capturing groups, `String::match` returns all matches found in your string.

There are two solutions for your problem:

- Remove `g` flag (why do you need it, anyway?).
- Use `pattern.exec(str)` instead of `str.match(pattern)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is due to the way you have broken it down onto each line?

I think in your case you are literally saying

```
    (.*)\n<img\ssrc="(.*)">\n(.*)
```

which would explain why pre is matched and the others aren't.

I don't know whether Java is like that but I did a similar thing in x++ and that was my problem.

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be tagged javascript, not java.  The multiline regex is a feature of coffeescript.  You can read about it here: http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/regular_expressions/heregexes